# Unable to Debug Local CLI Project

Tags: eclipse, phpeclipse

I've been working on a CLI project and I'm in desperate need of getting the debugger working.  I'm using Eclipse for PHP Developers 2021-09 (4.21.0) and recently updated from 2021-03.  I am running PHP 8.0.7.  I am able to create a PHP CLI Application run configuration.

[image: Run Config]

But when I go to Project -> Properties under the Run/Debug Settings section there are no launch configurations available and when I click New there is no option to create a new launch configuration for a CLI program.

[image: Project Run/Debug Settings]

My project runs fine and I'm able to echo out to the console but I absolutely cannot get this debugger to stop at any debug points. I've been unable to find any reference to this problem anywhere else.  Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got this working!  To get your debugger working for CLI programs, make the following environment changes:

php.ini, this line :
xdebug.mode = debug

Eclipse Preferences/PHP/Servers
Default PHP Web Server (Workspace Default) >>> http://localhost

Eclipse Preferences/PHP/Debug
PHP Server >>> Default PHP Web Server

Eclipse Preferences/PHP/Debug/Debuggers/
Xdebug / Configure / Debug Port 9003

Reference: https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&th=1107981&goto=1841480&#msg_1841480